# TCP timestamps field is in the future

Tags: centos, tcp

I have a server sending TCP packets. I noticed, with wireshark, that my packets in the Timestamp optional field look like

```
Timestamps: TSval 2552765291, TSecr 3858527953
```

The `TSval` is the value my server is giving to the packet. To my understanding the packet should have a timestamp to help against PAWS as well as to calculate TTL. But why is this timestamp in the future?

Furthermore, is the timestamp field related in any way with expiration of the packets or something that could cause the packet to be dropped at the destination?

My server runs CentOS 5

Comment: Why do you think the timestamp is "in the future"?

Comment: Isn't it 2552765291 secs from the Epoch? If so this is 2050.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TCP timestamp is a timestamp in the sense it increases proportionally as time passes. It is not normally aligned with the system clock but starts at some random value.

IP TTL uses a counter that gets decremented by each router a packet passes through not a timestamp.

Comment: Additionally the timestamp increase more often than once per second. Increasing 100 or 1000 times per second would be more likely.

The reference to TTL in the question must have been a mistake. Substitute TTL in the question with roundtrip time, then it makes more sense.